# Scrollable flow panel

Tags: java, swing

I need to create a panel where I can put some rectangles and it automatically reorder just inserting a scrollbar and growing up vertically. Also this panel can be resizable and again the rectangles must to be reordered to correctly be displayed inside the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question you want components to wrap to the next line so that the panel grows vertically while the width remains fixed.

If so then check out the [WrapLayout](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=wrap-layout)

Note: the `FlowLayout` already supports the wrapping of components to a new row on the panel. This issue is that the preferred size calculation assumes all components are placed on a single row. The `WrapLayout` overrides the preferred size calculation to support the wrapping of components on a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [JScrollPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).  If you never want a horizontal scroll bar you can add the following:

```
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

(By default the scroll pane will add horizontal and vertical scroll bars when required.)

The scroll pane itself will only be resizeable if you add it to a `Container` with the appropriate layout manager; e.g.

```
JFrame frm = new JFrame();
frm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
frm.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Adding a component to the CENTER will cause the component to grow as the frame is resized.
```